# Doctrine mapping to unknow entity

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine

is it possible to create a relation to a generic table/class whith Doctrine?

Here is some code to make it easier to understand:

```
// class Log...

// TODO:
// It could be useful to have a reference to
// the element mentioned by the log, the issue is
// we don't know what kind of entity it is.

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="???")
 */
private $elementId
```

Maybe instead of using `targetEntity` I could just use an int that is the id of the element located in the unknow table.

Comment: Have you tried using `ResolveTargetEntityListener`? http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html

Comment: @malarzm I think he simply wants to be able to bind his Logentity with all of his others entitites. ResolveTargetEntityListener seems to resolve the related type only once, when the metadata are cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in possibility now.

Let me propose a work around using [Doctrine Lifecycle Events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html) :

- Create 3 properties :

  ```
  /*
   * @ORM\Column(name="element_class", type="string")
   */
  private $elementClass

  /*
   * @ORM\Column(name="element_id", type="integer")
   */
  private $elementId

  // Not mapped
  private $element

  public function setElement($element)
  {
      $this->element = $element;
      $this->elementClass = get_class($element);
      $this->elementId = $element->getId();
  }

  public function getElement()
  {
      return $this->element;
  }

  // You need these for the PostLoad event listener :

  public function hydrateElementPostLoad($element)
  {
      $this->element = $element;
  }

  public function getElementClass()
  {
      return $this->elementClass;
  }

  public function getElementId()
  {
      return $this->elementId;
  }
  ```
- Then create a PostLoadListener able to hydrate the element property :

  ```
  namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

  use AppBundle\Entity\Log;

  class PostLoadListener
  {
      public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
      {
          $entity = $args->getEntity();

          if($entity instanceOf Log){
              $em = $args->getEntityManager();
              $entity->hydrateElementPostLoad(
                  $this->em->getRepository($entity->getElementClass())->findOneById($entity->getElementId())
              );
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- And register this event in your services.yml :

  ```
  services:
      places.listener:
          class: AppBundle\EventListener\PostLoadListener
          tags:
              - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
  ```

That's also how the most famous Bundle for logging works ([The Gedmo DoctrineExtensions Logger](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md))

- To retrieve all logs for an entity, create a repository method for your Log entity :

  ```
  getLogs($entity)
  {
      return $this->_em->findBy(array(
          'element_id'=>$entity->getId(),
          'element_class'=>get_class($entity)
      ));
  }
  ```

Comment: There is have a typo  `$this->dm->getRepository` ... it should be `em`.
And I get `There is no extension able to load the configuration for "my_app_test.listener"` when i try to update the schema. MyApp is the name of the app and TestBundle is the name of the bundle. Any advices?

Comment: What do you mean by `Your listener must be a service, not a config key` ?

Comment: If you declare your service as my_app_test.listener without the 4 spaces left, it will be interpreted as a config key.

Comment: I think I fixed the indentation but now I have a new issue : `circular reference detected for service "doctrine.dbal.default_connection", path: "doctrine.dbal.default_connection".`

Comment: OK, I edited my answer. You can get the entitymanager directly from $args. Remove the constructor and the argument in the service definition.

Comment: There is no problem anymore but the solution is kinda unsatisfactory, to request all the log for element x from class Y I have to do this: `findby(array("element_id" => $id, "element_class" => $class)` , or do I ?
This is what I was trying to avoid, I wished doctrine had a way to abstract the database access.

Comment: Edited my answer with a repository abstraction. Doctrine does not provide this abstraction. I gave you the method to do it yourself. I don't know how we can provide a better answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to manage some abstraction of one or more of your entities in the database level which is a headache,

Doctrine already has proposed Somme solutions to manage this kind of abstractions by using Inheritance Mapping

> A mapped superclass is an abstract or concrete class that provides persistent entity state and mapping information for its subclasses, but which is not itself an entity. Typically, the purpose of such a mapped superclass is to define state and mapping information that is common to multiple entity classes.

For more information check [this](http://doctrine2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)